# Jenkins Isn't Triggering Builds on SCM (SVN) External Project Change

Tags: svn, version-control, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a project:

```
/svn/repo/my_project/trunk/
```

which has an external dependency (configured with the svn:externals property) on:

```
/svn/repo/my_external_project/trunk/
```

Jenkins has no problem DL'ing the external project, but it isn't triggering a build when there is a change in the external project, which is the behavior I desire.

I have the "Included Regions" property set to

```
/trunk/.*
```

Is there something I need to add to that property, maybe deleting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can trigger Jenkins externally when a change in your external repository was made. Jenkins provides an interface for that you can use via a commit hook. I've seen something like that at the [SCM-Manager](http://www.scm-manager.org) with installed Jenkins plugin. There you can configure per repository which Jenkins project should be build on a commit.